# What exactly is the difference with Challenge mode?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've unlocked Challenge mode by beating the champion in Black 2. If I unlock it for a friend what changes exactly? [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Key_System) wasn't very specific, just mentioning that the AI becomes more challenging, higher level Pokemon, and more held items.

- Are the changes universal or limited to mostly important NPCs (gym leaders, Team Plasma leaders etc)?
- How does the AI improve? Does it swap Pokemon more often or is it mostly better move choices?
- Are all the Pokemon in the game higher level or just the trainers you battle throughout the game?
- What sort of held items does it unlock for the enemy? Does it increase the chance of wild Pokemon having a held item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best summary that I've found from Serebii:

> Challenge Mode is essentially the "Hard" setting of the game. Within
>   the Challenge Mode, the levels of Trainer's Pokémon will be higher,
>   starting at one level higher and reaching 5 levels higher at the end.
>   In addition to that, the AI of the opponents will be higher.
>
> In addition to this, the Gym Leaders and Elite Four will have an extra
>   Pokémon within their squads, and their other Pokémon shall have
>   different movesets and hold items.

Source: [Serebii Challenge Mode](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/easychallengemode.shtml)